# html meta viewport tag

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport

I build an html landing page, you can see it [here](http://tzabar.exactive.co.il/)
I used the meta viewport tag in that way:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

When I enter to this page from the mobile, the page width that not fit to the screen,
Iphone example - http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://tzabar.exactive.co.il/
what I've done wrong?

Comment: [Check this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). There are additional `viewport` content settings such as `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, `initial-scale` and `user-scalable` that may need to be set.

Comment: A question should include enough code to reproduce the issue and clearly state what the issue is. A link to a live page (here through an online service) is not enough; it becomes useless as soon as the page has been fixed or otherwise modified. And the `meta` tag does not magically make anything fit. It more or less tells the browser that you have designed things so that the page fits, without need for rescaling.

Answer (score 8):

---

As per War10ck's suggestion consider changing your viewport meta tag to something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You can also make changes in your CSS to help you along. Consider changing the .content class. For example:

```
.content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 930px;
}
```

I'm not sure what your ultimate design goal is, but that should get you moving in the right direction. You could also look into something like Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ to help you make sites responsive.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. He/She is trying to get it formatted for a mobile device...

Comment: @jmadden Thanks, I tried the both options, still don't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, follow the good advice from [jmadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990787/jmadden) and change your viewport tag to something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then at line 54 of style.css you have:

```
.content {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 35px auto;
}
```

You need to remove that 930px width or override it with media queries because at narrow viewports it's preventing your page layout from collapsing.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Should I change it to another fixed width, or will I have to use percentages where I have widths of ~1200px etc?

Comment: @Csteele5 - yes, setting fixed widths on elements will often give you trouble with mobile design, and the solution will depend in part on the specifics of your design. Maybe you can use percentages as you mention, or maybe you set a fixed width when the viewport is wide enough to display it, and then use media queries to set different properties on the element at narrower viewports. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp if you need help to get started with media queries. Good luck!