# Wrong container size in mobile

Tags: css, containers, meta, device-width

I have problems using the meta tag width="device-width" because the page loads zoomed in on mobiles.

After checking with the inspector I realized the site container has the "wrong" size on mobiles: even though in the CSS the width is set to 100% (I've also tried "width:auto;") the container is clearly just about 30% wide.

What could be the reason for this problem? Could it be just a missing  or some sort of syntax error in the code? Or an issue when loading js modules?

Comment: Can you edit the post with some of your markup and css? It may help diagnose the issue. 

However, without seeing anything I would guess the meta tag mat be incomplete. This is the meta tag I would use:


`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html meta viewport tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662621/html-meta-viewport-tag)

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure you added this line in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

second could you please share the container class code to figure out what is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the quick replies.

I had a min-width in relative (rem) units which caused the problem. I was confused as to the "relative" of rem units, and did not realize that they are only relative to a fixed quantity (the room em size).